# Share the shopping cart content between Magento multi-store websites

Tags: cart, magento-1.9, multistore, shopping-cart, websites

I have Magento multi-store websites that I want to user can add to his shopping cart products from all the website and pay once.

I successfully done it using [this article](http://turnkeye.com/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores).

But when the user click on the product in the shopping cart, he is not redirected to the right website. It's a limitation the described in the article at the end.

> The link for editing items in the cart will redirect customer to original cart website. It is possible to change it, you can override getUrl method for cart items block or override controller.

I couldn't find any explaination how to do this override.

Someone can help me do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea.
You can add a field to the `sales_flat_quote_item` table and keep in it the store view id of the store of the product, when adding it to the cart.
Then change the `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` (and the ones from bundle and downloadable) and replace the default link with the one that points to the right store.

So

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl() ?>">....
```

becomes:

```
<?php $usedStore = $_item->get store id column value here?>
<a href="<?php echo $_item->getProduct()->setStoreId($usedStore)->getUrlInStore() ?>">....
```

The code above is just an idea. I'm not 100% sure it works.

Comment: Hi Marius, Thank you for your comment. I'm new with magento. Can you help me with this? What I need to do and how i'm doing it?